# postgres orm: current transaction is aborted

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, peewee

I am using peewee ORM (http://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and when I try to make a wrong insert,
I am getting `InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

For example,
the database connector is initialised like this:

```
database = PostgresqlDatabase('ip_spotlight', autocommit=True, autorollback=True, **{'password': 'xxx', 'host': 'x.x.x.x', 'port': 5432, 'user': 'xxx'})
```

and I try to do the following `insert`

```
try:
    BgpCommunities.create(comm_name="BBB", comm_value="1111:2222", label="bbb", used_as="")
except Exception as e:
    database.rollback()
```

*the database connection is locked, thus all sub-sequent queries will fail inevitably.*

There is a related discussion over here: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/240

But I am not abel to figure it how to deal with it. Could you please advise ?

Comment: Have you tried not setting autorollback?

Comment: thanks! removing  `autocommit=True, autorollback=True` seems to work